# Listview item or subitem onchange event

Tags: vb.net, charts, controls

When I have a listview with like 46 items, where each item has 4 subitems, the values of the subitems are changing with time, I use the values of subitems to draw a pie chart when an item in the list view is selected using this code:

```
Chart1.Series("Series1").ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie
Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.Clear()

If ListView3.FocusedItem.SubItems(1).Text > 0 Then
    Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddY(ListView3.FocusedItem.SubItems(1).Text)
End If
If ListView3.FocusedItem.SubItems(2).Text > 0 Then
    Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddY(ListView3.FocusedItem.SubItems(2).Text)
End If
If ListView3.FocusedItem.SubItems(3).Text > 0 Then
    Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddY(ListView3.FocusedItem.SubItems(3).Text)
End If
If ListView3.FocusedItem.SubItems(4).Text > 0 Then
    Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddY(ListView3.FocusedItem.SubItems(4).Text)
End If
```

Is there a way to detect a change of a subitem's value? Like `onchange` event in textbox, but for items or subitems, because I want the pie chart to update when a subitem value changes.
this code changes the sub items

```
For xx As Integer = 0 To ListView3.Items.Count - 1
                If ListView3.Items(xx).SubItems(0).Text = googleXMLdocument...<s:name>(j).Value Then

                    If j + 1 = 1 Then
                        ListView3.Items(xx).SubItems(1).Text += 1

                    End If
                    If j + 1 = 2 Then
                        ListView3.Items(xx).SubItems(2).Text += 1
                    End If
                    If j + 1 = 3 Then
                        ListView3.Items(xx).SubItems(3).Text += 1
                    End If
                    If j + 1 > 4 Then
                        ListView3.Items(xx).SubItems(4).Text += 1
                    End If
                End If

            Next
```

Comment: How are the items/subitems changing? Manually by clicking or via code?

Comment: i already did it using 4 labels each holds the value of a sub item and  and a timer this way i got a real time charting...answer to your question they change with time data is parsed from google atom feed

Comment: You don't need a timer for this :)

Comment: i don't know what i need..i am new to this stuff :D..it worked anyway

Comment: but how would you do it without a timer?

Comment: Could you please answer the question in my first comment?

Comment: i said the are updated by code, some times a value changes more than 30 times in one minute

Comment: Ok I had not seen the edit. Create a common procedure which will be called every time right after the code changes the sub items. This way you will not need the timer. The common procedure will automatically update it every time the values change.

Comment: this is the problem! i don't know if the code changed the sub items or not..since they are changing alot i think timer is the best way, like redraw every one second

Comment: Can you share the code which changes the subitems

Comment: i added the code, j is the counter for the main loop

Comment: Great. Now add the chart updating code after the last `Next`. This way the chart will automatically get updated if there is any change in the subitems. You will not require a timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. This way the chart will automatically get updated if there is any change in the subitems. You will not require a timer.

```
For xx As Integer = 0 To ListView3.Items.Count - 1
    If ListView3.Items(xx).SubItems(0).Text = googleXMLdocument...<s:name>(j).Value Then
        If j + 1 = 1 Then
            ListView3.Items(xx).SubItems(1).Text += 1
        End If
        If j + 1 = 2 Then
            ListView3.Items(xx).SubItems(2).Text += 1
        End If
        If j + 1 = 3 Then
            ListView3.Items(xx).SubItems(3).Text += 1
        End If
        If j + 1 > 4 Then
            ListView3.Items(xx).SubItems(4).Text += 1
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Put the below code after the above code in a loop. You can also do away with the `FocusedItem`

```
Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.Clear()

Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddY (ListView3.FocusedItem.SubItems(1).Text)
Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddY (ListView3.FocusedItem.SubItems(2).Text)
Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddY (ListView3.FocusedItem.SubItems(3).Text)
Chart1.Series("Series1").Points.AddY (ListView3.FocusedItem.SubItems(4).Text)
```